# How can I select the adjacent table cell using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I really need your help with this,

How can I select the adjacent table cell from my select box and insert some text?

It seems that the following code is not working as I thought it would, starting at the reference point whose classname is .selectbox and maybe there is better way of doing this, so i'm open to suggestions.

```
$('#fin-code-alot').closest('.selectbox').next().html('test')
```

Here's the hierarchy/markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Allotment:</td>
        <td>
            <div class="selectbox">
                <div class="selectric-selectbox">
                <select id="fin-code-alot" class="custom-options">
                    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value="120">120</option>
                    <option value="12D">12D</option>            
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Put Some Text Here</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you want the table cell then get closest `td` and then call next, `.selectBox` is a div not the parent cell `$('#fin-code-alot').closest('td').next()`

Comment: `closest` is only seeking **upwards** in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is only selecting the `<div class="selectbox">` element, which has no next sibling.

You need to select the [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) table cell and then its [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling:

```js
$('#fin-code-alot').closest('td').next('td').text('test')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Allotment:</td>
        <td>
            <div class="selectbox">
                <div class="selectric-selectbox">
                <select id="fin-code-alot" class="custom-options">
                    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                    <option value="120">120</option>
                    <option value="12D">12D</option>            
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Put Some Text Here</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In addition, I'd recommend using the safer [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method if you are only inserting text, instead of `.html()`. Of course you'll need to use the latter if you need to insert HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

`.selectbox` has no `next()`, you need to go further upwards using `closest('td')`:

```
$('#fin-code-alot').closest('td').next().text('test')
```